# SharePoint 2010 Site Customization: Removed breadcrumb and now receiving errors

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, breadcrumbs

I removed the following fields from the "s4-titletext" cell using the Manage Content Regions in SPD:

- PlaceHolderSiteName
- PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea
- PlaceHolderPageDescription

And I added "SharePoint:SPLinkButton...  **Visible="False"**

I have published this template and have set it as the Default Master. It displays fine but when I add a web part (not in SPD), I get the error `"You must specify a value for this required field"` and it will not let me add/remove the web part or change any list. What did I do wrong in my customization? I followed the instructions on [this post](http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2012/12/sharepoint-2010-hide-the-title-and-description-from-ribbon/). I used Option 2 to hide the words. The reason I removed the fields is because I want to stretch our banner across the whole page and I didn't want to leave the space where the bread crumb would have been. My "s4-titletext" area looks like the pictures on the top of the page, only banner is stretched all across the top of page. I can not add a link to my page due to it being on a private server. I have asked other SharePoint experts and they are stumped as well. Thank you for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting visible="false", getting hiding the control using a CSS class. Set the control's class to something like 'hiddenClass' and then define your class style.

```
.hiddenClass{display: none;}
```

Customizing SharePoint masterpages is a pain since they're so sensitive. You have to use this method when hiding a lot of the out of the box controls.

Answer (score 0):

Some placeholders need to be on the master page, if you remove it it will cause errors in some of the scrips.

What I recommend to you is create a hidden div and inside of it put all the placeholder you want to hide, like the example bellow.

```
<div style="display:none">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleZone" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<div>
```

Comment: I still get the error when I tried this. It removed everything easier than going through Content Regions because I could just go back and edit them. I am going to try and hide these areas in the CSS as mentioned above and see what happens.